# getenv() is some times returning false in CodeIgniter 4. Why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4, dotenv

I am loading table data fetched using Ajax in a table with datatables. The logic fetches some value from the .env file using `getenv()` function. This getenv() is returning false only some of the times and otherwise not.

I tried opening the URL (HTTP GET) which datatables use to fetch the data thru Ajax in a browser, and there it does not seem a problem at all.

```
public function ap_FetchData()
{
    $accountLibrary = new Account();
    if($accountLibrary->checkIsUserLogged())
    {
        // do some stuff and print JSON - dummy logic
        $data = [];
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
        {
            $image = getBucketURL($i.".jpg");
            $data[] = $image;
        }
        outPutAsJSON($data);
    }
    else outPutAsJSON("Your session is timed-out. Please login again.", 403);
}
```

Some times I get the JSON output with the Bucket URLs (partial) and sometimes I get session is timed-out error. However, this sessions timed-out behavior is seen only on the AJAX.

The `checkIsUserLogged` is at Account.php at Libraries directory

```
function checkIsUserLogged(): bool
{
    $sessionName = getenv("session.name"); // this is the session name stored in env file sometimes and false sometimes 
    // do validation and return true or false
}
```

The getBucketURL() is at a helper file.

```
function getBucketURL($key)
{
    return getenv("s3bucket.url").$key;
    /*
     * some times this return as http://www.example.com/$key
     * and
     * some times it return only $key
     * var_dump(getenv("s3bucket.url")) outputs (bool) false is second case
     */
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "http://www.example.com/1.jpg",
    "http://www.example.com/2.jpg",
    "http://www.example.com/3.jpg",
    .
    .
    "http://www.example.com/10.jpg"
}
```

**Actual problematic Output:**

```
{
    "1.jpg",
    "2.jpg",
    "3.jpg",
    .
    .
    "10.jpg"
}
```

**Edit**

`$_SERVER["s3bucket.url]`, `$_ENV["s3bucket.url]` and `$_SERVER["session.name]`, `$_ENV["session.name]` works perfect. Seems the problem is only with `getenv()`

[image: Output]

Comment: How about `$_ENV["s3bucket.url"];` ?

Comment: Hi @steven7mwesigwa, both `$_ENV["s3bucket.url"]` and `$_SERVER["s3bucket.url"]` returns correct string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more *'bulletproof'* solution, use CodeIgniter 4's helper function:

[`env(string $key, $default = null)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/821abab8dfd71713b9c719eb254530cd4c7c750f/system/Common.php#L382).

I.e:

```php
echo env("s3bucket.url");
```

It first searches for the *'key'* in the [`$_ENV`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment) variable, then the [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) environment variable and lastly, the [`getenv(string $varname, bool $local_only = false)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) PHP function.

---

###### EXCERPT FROM:

https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/Common.php

```php
if (! function_exists('env')) {
    /**
     * Allows user to retrieve values from the environment
     * variables that have been set. Especially useful for
     * retrieving values set from the .env file for
     * use in config files.
     *
     * @param string|null $default
     *
     * @return bool|string|null
     */
    function env(string $key, $default = null)
    {
        $value = $_ENV[$key] ?? $_SERVER[$key] ?? getenv($key);

        // Not found? Return the default value
        if ($value === false) {
            return $default;
        }

        // Handle any boolean values
        switch (strtolower($value)) {
            case 'true':
                return true;

            case 'false':
                return false;

            case 'empty':
                return '';

            case 'null':
                return null;
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Steven, thank you for this. `env` prints the value as expected on both GET and POST requests.